# Dynamically changing legend AmCharts4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

The columns that have (maximum Additional Hedging) are sometimes on the chart and sometimes not this is determined on the dynamic data that can be changed constantly via a draggable bar above the chart. 
I want to be able have the legend of the chart to remove these items when they aren't on the and bring them back when they are on the chart.
This is currently working on the AmCharts3 version of the chart but I am upgrading them.

```
var chart = am4core.create("fxExposureHedgingChart", am4charts.XYChart);


let title = chart.titles.create();
title.text = this.props.title;
title.fontSize = 25;
title.marginBottom = 30;

chart.data = this.props.dataProvider;
chart.dateFormatter.inputDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
chart.orderByField = "name"

var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "category";
categoryAxis.title.text = "Time";
categoryAxis.renderer.startLocation = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.10;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.90;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.location = 0.5 ;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.wrap = false;
categoryAxis.renderer.labels.template.truncate = false;

categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 30;
categoryAxis.layout = "horizontal";
// Create value axis
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.title.text = "Amount " + this.state.displayCurrency;
valueAxis.max = 140000;
valueAxis.min = 0;


let valueAxis2 = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis2.title.text = "Rate";
valueAxis2.renderer.opposite = true;
valueAxis2.min = 1.1000;
valueAxis2.max = 1.4500;


let createColumnSeries = () => {
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
    series.dataFields.valueY = "exposure";
    series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
    series.name = "Forecasted Cashflows";
    series.yAxis = valueAxis;
    series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(85);
    series.stacked = false;

    series.tooltip.dy = -8;
    series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
    var columnTemplate = series.columns.template;
        columnTemplate.column.fillOpacity = 0.8;
        columnTemplate.tooltipText = "{name} ({category}): {valueY}";
        columnTemplate.tooltipY = 0;
    var columnHoverState = columnTemplate.column.states.create("hover");
        columnHoverState.properties.fillOpacity = 1;
        columnHoverState.properties.cornerRadiusTopLeft = 35;
        columnHoverState.properties.cornerRadiusTopRight = 35;

    return series;
}

let createLineSeries1 = () => {
    var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
        series.dataFields.valueY = "achieveableRate";
        series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
        series.name = "Achieveable Rate";
        series.tooltipText = "{valueY.value}";
        series.strokeWidth = 2;
        series.yAxis = valueAxis2;

        let bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.Bullet());
        let square = bullet.createChild(am4core.Rectangle);
        square.width = 5;
        square.height = 5;
        square.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        square.verticalCenter = "middle";
        series.bullets.getIndex(0).tooltipText = "{name}: {valueY}";



        return series;
}




let getDealGraphInfo = (classIds,data) =>{
    let maxHedgingClassIDs = classIds.map( id => (data.reduce((accum, row) => accum+ (row["maxAmount_"+id]),0)) > 0 ? id: null);
    let maxAmounts = maxHedgingClassIDs.map((id, index) => {

        if(id === null){} else {
            let HedgingSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
            HedgingSeries.dataFields.valueY = "maxAmount_" + id;
            HedgingSeries.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
            HedgingSeries.name = classIDtoDisplayName(id).replace(/FX\s/,"") + " (Maximum Additional Hedging)";
            HedgingSeries.tooltip.dy = -8;
            HedgingSeries.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
            HedgingSeries.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(70);
            HedgingSeries.id = classIDtoDisplayName(id).replace(/\s/g,"").toLowerCase() + "_maxAmount";
            HedgingSeries.stacked = true;

            var columnTemplate = HedgingSeries.columns.template;
            columnTemplate.column.fillOpacity = 0.8;
            columnTemplate.tooltipText = HedgingSeries.name;
            columnTemplate.tooltipY = 0;
    }}).filter(c => c);


    return classIds.map((id, index) => {
        let Series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
        Series.dataFields.valueY = "amount_" + id;
        Series.dataFields.categoryX = "category";
        Series.name = classIDtoDisplayName(id).replace(/FX\s/,"");
        Series.tooltip.dy = -8;
        Series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
        Series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(70);
        Series.id = classIDtoDisplayName(id).replace(/\s/g,"").toLowerCase();
        Series.strokewidth = 1;
        Series.stacked = true;

        var columnTemplate = Series.columns.template;
        columnTemplate.column.fillOpacity = 0.8;
        columnTemplate.tooltipText = Series.name;
        columnTemplate.tooltipY = 0;

        return Series;

    }).concat(maxAmounts).sort((a,b) => (a.name < b.name ? -1:1));

}

let budgetRateName = getBudgetRateName(this.props.budgetRate);

getDealGraphInfo(this.props.dealClassIds,this.state.data).concat(createColumnSeries(),
createLineSeries1(),
createLineSeries2(),
createLineSeries3(),
createLineSeries4(budgetRateName)
).sort((a,b) => (a.name < b.name ? -1:1));

    chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
    chart.legend.itemContainers.template.paddingTop = 5;
    chart.legend.itemContainers.template.paddingBottom = 5;
    chart.legend.labels.template.wrap = true;
    chart.legend.labels.template.maxWidth = 350;
    chart.legend.labels.template.truncate = true;
    chart.legend.useDefaultMarker = true;
    chart.exporting.menu = new am4core.ExportMenu();
    var plugin = chart.plugins.push(new am4plugins_annotation.Annotation());



    var markerTemplate = chart.legend.markers.template
    markerTemplate.width = 10;
    markerTemplate.height = 10;

    this.setState({chart: chart})
  }

  componentDidUpdate(oldProps, prevState){
    if (oldProps.dataProvider !== this.props.dataProvider){
        this.state.chart.data = this.props.dataProvider;
    } 
}

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.dispose();
    }
  }
```

getDealGraphInfo are the columns that are being added/removed. Note, the object always has these columns but when they have no value it is set to "null" otherwise it has a value. 
When I drag the bar above the chart I am using componentDidUpdate to change the data on the chart. So I believe the solution could have something to do in here.

Comment: So I have found that when the chart is created the legend is created with the specific data. But the legend does not update as the data is added/removed. Even that the chart itself does not update when data is added/removed. What I mean by this is that the chart will update the data inside itself but if a new column is needed to be added the chart will not add it, instead it will keep the same columns that it was created with.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temp fix where in componentDidUpdate I dispose the chart and recreate the whole chart when I receive new props. But this is very laggy when using the slider. I would prefer to just have the legend/data in the chart update, than needing to recreate the chart every time.